# Microsoft recommends 32bit IIS 7 AppPools on 64bit machines. Why?

Tags: asp.net, iis

Looking at number of resources I've found out this weird recommendation. Or to quote Steve Schofield:

For optimal performance, use x64 based systems running 32 bit mode applicatoin pools. You'll get 4 GB per application pool.

http://forums.iis.net/t/1149410.aspx

Also, same recommendation can be found in this Mix 08 talk - [Everything You Need to Know about Diagnostics and Debugging on Microsoft Internet Information Services 7](http://channel9.msdn.com/Events/MIX/MIX08/T06)

So, what is the reason behind it?

EDIT: Microsoft doesn't recommend this for compatibility, but also for **performance** reasons and I'm interested in this topic exactly because of that. Here is one more link that better explains what I'm talking about:
http://learn.iis.net/page.aspx/201/32-bit-mode-worker-processes/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. On compatibility side, not all the web applications and dependencies are 64 bit ready. Start from 32 bit on IIS help avoid lots of trouble at the very beginning. If your application happens to be 64 bit ready, you can start from 64 bit. Otherwise, you are stuck.
2. Microsoft does not have good tools to debug 64 bit issues for non-advanced developers yet (in 2008 that was true, and it is true even today). Even if you are an IIS geek, debugging 32 bit worker process is much simpler than debugging the 64 bit one.

The migration to 64 bit will finally finish (thinking about the 16 to 32 bit migration in 1990s).

I don't believe that you should stick to "Microsoft recommends 32 bit" or "Steve Scholfield said that". All should depend on your own application, and your unique environment. Those conclusions were drawn for other scenarios, which may not even apply a bit to your case.

**Edited:** In fact Microsoft's guys explain the performance gain of using 32 bit better in this VS related blog post,

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ricom/archive/2009/06/10/visual-studio-why-is-there-no-64-bit-version.aspx

Comment: Read my EDIT... and please do not give me philosophical answer (e.g: all depends, and let's turn this into philosophical discussion).

Comment: The article has a link for you to send emails, so you'd better consult its author directly.